# css issue: absolute positioned span would not extend out of containing div

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

as you can see in the following image, i have a simple form that validates the fields in real time and generates a `span` that says whether that field is valid or not. problem is, for some reason that span would not extend out of the containing div even though its has `position:absolute` in its css rule. by the way, the span gets its `right` position using javascript, that calculates the width of that field (since every field differs in width). any suggestions?

[image: register form css issue]

here is the css code:

```
div.row {
    background:url('/img/formBackground.gif') repeat;
    margin:0 2px 2px 2px;border-radius:10px 0 10px 0;
    position:relative
}

.row span.valid,
.row span.invalid {
    line-height:18px;
    height:20px;padding:0 22px 0 5px;
    display:block;font-size:13px;
    border-radius:3px;position:absolute;
    z-index:100;top:4px;right:160px
}
```

here is the html code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">דואר אלקטרוני: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="width:250px" dir="ltr"/>
    </div>
```

here is the javascript code:

```
email.onchange = function validateEmail() {
    span = document.getElementById('span4');
    span.style.right = calcDistance(email);
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    el = email.value;
    if(el == null || el == '') {span.setAttribute('class','invalid');span.innerHTML = "<span></span>עליך להזין דוא\"ל";return false;}
    if(reg.test(el) == false) {span.setAttribute('class','invalid');span.innerHTML = "<span></span>כתובת הדוא\"ל אינה תקינה";return false;}
    else {span.setAttribute('class','valid');span.innerHTML = "<span></span>תקין";return true;}
}

    function calcDistance(el) {
    var spanDistance = 160 + 20;
    var targetWidth = el.offsetWidth;
    return targetWidth + spanDistance + 'px';
}
```

This is how I want it to look (the `span` extends out of the containing `div`). I was able to get this result only by giving a certain `width` to the `span`, which is not a good solution because every message differs in it's width:

[image: register form with live validation]

Comment: Can we see a live version of this somewhere? Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Shrink the size of the input box to accomodate the long error message?

Comment: ok, here it is, the full code in jsfiddle: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/xncSK/2/)

Comment: ok guys I fixed it!! I saw this in an old Stack Overflow post. the problem was in the css rule of the span. all I neede to do was to add: `white-space:nowrap`. thats it! by the way, do you know how can I mark this post as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into some old posts, I managed to solve the problem by adding `white-space:no-wrap;` to the `span` CSS rule.

Answer (score 3):

Elements with `position:relative` will "trap" any absolutely positioned child elements. In other words, the absolute element's coordinates are relative to the parent.

- http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html (see "The containing block" section)

While calculating the input widths to create your error message width is clever, this might just be too fragile of a design. You may end up with error messages that are simply too small for the message itself, especially when you consider that you don't truly have 100% control over the user's font size.

There's not enough code here to reproduce the output in your image, but possible solutions or workarounds may include:

- Remove `position:relative` from `div.row`
- Change your design, and move the error message underneath the input instead

Comment: I used the width of the input to calculate the **position** of the error message, not the width of the error message. one thing i have noticed was that when i didnt use the javascript code, the error message `span` will extend out of the containing div. maybe the problem is in the javascript code?

Comment: Ok I see, well you really shouldn't have to do that, but it's tough to tell without the code to reproduce it. If you can post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net I'm sure it's easily resolved, and if you can be a little more explicit in explaining what you want to happen that would be a great help too.

Comment: thank you @Madmartigan, here is a [link for the code in jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xncSK/2)

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you want to happen, but what about this: http://jsfiddle.net/xncSK/3/ See the bottom of the CSS pane for what I changed. Your empty divs that serve as dividers, shims, and clearfixing are all pretty much unnecessary and make it a little difficult to work with the way you have things placed. Of course, doing without them would require rewriting all the CSS...

Comment: im trying to make the `span` extend **out** of the containing `div`. i have updated my original post with a new picture to show you what im aiming for.